# Bash; change directory to folders start with 2* or 21*

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a series of folders which are named based on the date of creation and some other information; i.e.

```
220310_AS
220307_DF
220228_1A
..
211228_QR
..
201224_HH
```

How can I in a bash script loop over folders which start with 22 or 21?
Here is part of my code which does not work

```
..
for dd in */2*; do
    cd "$dd"
    #do something
    eval "ls"
    cd ..
..
```

Comment: Why do you do `eval "ls"` instead of just `ls`?

Comment: @Barmar I wrote it as an example, I was not aware that only "ls" also works, thank you.

Comment: You almost never need to use `eval`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your wildcard `*/2*` matches directories 2 levels below the original directory. So to get back to the original directory, you need `cd ../..` instead of `cd ..`.

You could also do the `cd` in a subshell, then simply exiting the shell will return you to the original directory.

```
for dd in */2*; do (
    cd "$dd"
    # do stuff
); done
```

Comment: Thank you. I have tried your second option, but it says `cd: */2*: No such file or directory`

Comment: Then the folders aren't nested a level below. Maybe you mean `for dd in 2*`?